# The class of all iterated antiderivatives of rational functions

Tags: real-analysis, rational-functions

Consider the following property of a function $f$:

> There exists a non-negative integer $n$ such that the $n$'th derivative of $f$ is a rational function.

Question 1: Is there a name in the literature for this property?

Question 2: Are there any good references for reading about the class of all such functions?

Comment: In algebraic geometry, we would usually keep track of the differential equation, rather than its solution space.  Then, roughly, this is a coherent D-module with regular singularities at the poles of the rational function.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that's a good point. But I want to take the union of these solution spaces over all rational functions and all $n$. Then my feeling is that I get something bigger than a coherent D-module, and I would like a name for this large space of functions.

Comment: The rational functions have a basis consisting of the functions $x^n$ and $\frac{1}{(x - r)^n}$ (say we're working over $\mathbb{C}$) so it suffices to understand the antiderivatives of these functions. These have a basis consisting of the previous basis along with the functions $(x - r)^n \log (x - r)$. Is there anything else to say?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan ...  What else to say?  Antiderivatives of those.   For example, $\int (\log x)/x\;dx$ is not elementary.  On the other hand, can we see that we do not get $e^x$ ... so that we do not even get all elementary functions.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: Don't you mean $\int x dx/(\log x)$?

Comment: @BenCrowell ... right, I had the wrong example.   So is QiaochuYuan correct: we only need those functions, and it is closed under anti-derivatives?

Comment: @Gerald: neither $\frac{\log x}{x}$ nor $\frac{x}{\log x}$ have the property. When you take the antiderivative of $x^n \log x$ you get a constant times $x^{n+1} \log x$ plus a polynomial. So no other functions are necessary. You can see this on the level of formal power series (ignoring $\frac{1}{x}$ for simplicity): taking repeated antiderivatives of rational formal power series (=polynomial-exponential coefficients) adds denominators of the form $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2) \dots}$ which you can reduce to linear combinations of denominators of the form $\frac{1}{n+k}$ using partial fractions.